# keep the header of file before sorting in csh

Tags: linux, csh

I have the below file.rpt:

```
Data Manhattan Wire Wire
Delay Distance Length Diff[%]
############################# 
0.558 728.282 738.89 1%
0.481 255.258 285.887 12%
0.552 652.888 677.985 4%
0.431 420.896 477.73 14%
0.506 580.288 633.018 9%
0.388 350.22 463.05 32%
0.541 622.088 672.761 8%
0.462 384.064 586.98 53%
0.565 574.016 594.434 4%
0.470 339.268 450.927 33%
0.566 664.304 672.092 1%
0.441 436.428 534.146 22%
```

I'm trying to sort one of the column and keep the 3 lines header without any change.
How can I do it without manipulate to other file?

I tried something similar to the below:
`head -3 file.rpt ; sort -nrk4,4 file.rpt | -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this doesn't really count as a `csh` answer, but:

```
sh -c '{ sed 3q file.rpt; sed 1,3d file.rpt | sort -nrk4,4; }'
```

In `csh`, you can do:

```
( sed 3q file.rpt; sed 1,3d file.rpt | sort -nrk4,4; )
```

Comment: Since the file is very long while using this suggestion I can't see the header.
For that I use pipe and less ` | less` at the end and the header can't be shown

Comment: `( sed 3q file.rpt ; sed 1,3d file.rpt | sort -nrk4,4 ; ) | less` seems to work just fine.

Comment: You Right!!! it work.

Do you know how can I set it as alias?
After extract the header I want to add additional manipulation.
I tried something like the below but I loose the header

'''alias hd 'set col = \!:1 ; set file = \!:2 ; (sed ${col}q $file ; sed 1,${col}d $file ; \!$)''''

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
head -3 file.rpt ; tail -n +4 file.rpt | sort -nrk4,4
```

- `-n`: output the last X lines
- `+4`: output starting with line 4.  Hence skip the first 3 lines
- use `|` to send the output of `tail` as the input to `sort`.

Result:

```
Data Manhattan Wire Wire
Delay Distance Length Diff[%]
############################# 
0.462 384.064 586.98 53%
0.470 339.268 450.927 33%
0.388 350.22 463.05 32%
0.441 436.428 534.146 22%
0.431 420.896 477.73 14%
0.481 255.258 285.887 12%
0.506 580.288 633.018 9%
0.541 622.088 672.761 8%
0.565 574.016 594.434 4%
0.552 652.888 677.985 4%
0.566 664.304 672.092 1%
0.558 728.282 738.89 1%
```

Comment: Since the file is very long while using this suggestion I can't see the header.
For that I use pipe and less ` | less` at the end and the header can't be shown

Comment: Modified accordingly

Comment: In a big file when you concatenate `less` at the end you can't see the header.

Comment: he?  Scroll up your terminal.  Or send the result to an output file and `less` that file.